# Error while overloading operator (must be a nonstatic member function)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing string class on my own. And I have such code. I just want to overload `operator=`. This is my actual code, and I get error in last part of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class S {
    public:
        S();
        ~S() { delete []string;}
        S &operator =(const S &s);

    private:
        char *string;
        int l;
};

S::S()
{
    l = 0;
    string = new char[1];
    string[0]='\0';
}

S &operator=(const S &s)
{
    if (this != &s)
    {
        delete []string;
        string = new char[s.l+1];
        memcpy(string,s.string,s.l+1);
        return *this;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

But unfortunately I get error 'S& operator=(const S&)' must be a nonstatic member function.

Comment: This code snippet compiles for me with g++.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but the function compiles fine with `memcpy` declared: http://liveworkspace.org/code/92ac98695817213f6c15af241904d165

Comment: You are not missing a semicolon after the class definition, are you?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, That's what I guessed, but I've never come across this error from doing that. Is there a specific compiler that does?

Comment: @chris Ah, the missing semicolon after the declaraion... It can bring so many fun errors :)

Comment: Your assignment operator is private and you are missing a `;` at the end of the class declaration. Post some minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Since no one's mentioned it, the term is *overload*, not *reload*. @dasblinkenlight, Yes, fun... Maybe after you get them often enough that you realize what the cause is right away.

Comment: I use G++ compiler, and for sure I added required libraries.

Comment: Copy and paste your actual code.  All of it. Enough to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are missing class name:

This is global operator, `=` cannot be global:

```
S &operator=(const S &s)
```

You must define this as class function:

```
S & S::operator=(const S &s)
//  ^^^
```

Comment: for god's sake!

Answer (score 7):

I believe PiotrNycz has provided the reasonable answer. Here please pardon me to add one more word.

In c++, assignment operator overloading function couldn't be `friend function`. Using friend function for operator=, will cause the same compiler error "overloading = operator must be a nonstatic member function".

Comment: This should really be a comment on the other answer, if it's just a clarification. Alternatively, remove the note about it being "one more word" and make it a proper answer.