# Overloading operator= for double

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload = operator of type double?

I have the following:

```
double operator=(double a, Length b) {
    return a = (b.getInches()/12+b.getFeet())*3.2808*0.9144;
}
```

It throws the following error:

```
'double operator=(double, Length)' must be a nonstatic member function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you want `Length` to be convertible to `double` to support expressions like `Length a; double b; b = a;`. Convertible means that `Length` has `operator double`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while overloading = operator (must be a nonstatic member function)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848171/error-while-overloading-operator-must-be-a-nonstatic-member-function)

Comment: Do you really want to overload the assignment operator? maybe you want to overload the conversion from `Length` to `double`, in that case you shoule overload `Length::operator double()`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot overload operators for builtin (integral or floating point) types like `double`, and also you cannot globally overload the `=` operator for *any* type.  The `=` operator can only be overloaded as a class member function.

See also: [Can I define an operator overload that works with built-in / intrinsic / primitive types?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/intrinsics-and-operator-overloading.html)

Answer (score 8):

You cannot overload the assignment operator for a primitive type, but you can supply an operator that converts `Length` to `double`, giving you the desired effect:

```
class Length {
    ...
public:
    operator double() {
        return (getInches()/12+getFeet())*3.2808*0.9144;
    }
};

main() {
    Length len = ...;
    ...
    double d = len;
}
```

Note that this conversion should be done only when the conversion is perfectly clear to the reader. For example, in this case you should make a `get_yard` member function, like this:

```
class Length {
    ...
public:
    double get_yards() {
        return (getInches()+12*getFeet())/ 36.0;
    }
};
```

Note that you do not need to convert feet to meters and then to yards - you can go straight from feet to yards; the conversion factor is `3.0`. You can also do the division last - see the modified expression above.

Comment: It might be good to mention the potential downsides to this approach, namely ambiguity, and various workarounds.

Comment: @staticx I agree, this should be done only when the conversion is perfectly clear to the reader. When it is not, one should use a member function. I edited the answer to mention this. Thanks!

Comment: @Roddy :):):) You're right - I divided 12 by 3 instead of multiplying (a consequence of growing up in a country where they teach only the metric system). I should have checked my math, though... Thanks!